# Convert List <double> to Double

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to convert the double type of list into a double variable, my code is something like this...

```dart
var _first=<double> [108,105,90.833,87.7,88.6];
     var _answers=<double>[];
     for (var i=0; i<_first.length;i++){
       _answers.add(_first[i]);
       double _cosa = Angle.degrees(_first[i]).cos;
       print(_cosa);
       print(_cosa[0]);
double a=_cosa[0];
double b=_cosa[1];
double c=_cosa[2];
double d=_cosa[3];
double e=_cosa[4];
}
```

_cosa variable printing 5 answers e.g: 1,2,3,4,5.
I want to get all answers in 5 different variables.
but this method throws an error.

Comment: You are using `_answers` instead `_first[i]` when passing the argument to the `Angle.degrees` function

Comment: call index of your list

Answer (score 0):

This should be your updated code

```
var _first=<double> [108,105,90.833,87.7,88.6];
var _answers=<double>[];

for (var i=0; i<_first.length;i++){
  _answers.add(_first[i]);
  double _cosa = Angle.degrees(_first[i]).cos;  ///<-- updated
}
```

the problem was that you were passing a list of numbers to a parameter/input that receives a number value, here i.e double.

We know that CosA is found for angle, i.e a single value not a list of values.

Hope this helps. Upvote if it did :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what you're trying to do is:

```
var _first=<double> [108,105,90.833,87.7,88.6];
var _answers=<double>[];

for (var i=0; i<_first.length;i++){
  _answers.add(Angle.degrees(_first[i]).cos);
}
```